# how to get results from mongoDB where _id is string objectId

Tags: mongodb, objectid

in my mongo database _id is string from ObjectId like this:

[image]

when I make this query I get results but with wrong sorting

```
db.collection.find({ _id : {$gt:"57c03e6288579757b5172d51"} });
```

how to fix that ?

Comment: Have you tried this ? `db.collection.find({ _id : "57c03e6288579757b5172d51"});`

Comment: If you want it sorted by `_id`, you have to do that explicitly by chaining `.sort({_id: 1})` to your command. Is that what you mean by "wrong sorting"?

Comment: @John your query work but I need to pass $gt 'greater than'

Comment: @JohnnyHK thank you but I need results that have _id greater than passed _id in query

Comment: @ehab Sure, that's why you chain the calls together: `db.collection.find({ _id : {$gt:"57c03e6288579757b5172d51"} }).sort({_id: 1});`. Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query by inserting the objectID string with $gt operator.
You will have to create an objectID.

```
var objID = ObjectId("57c03e6288579757b5172d51");
db.collection.find({ _id : {$gt: objID} });
```

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: From mongo db compass you can use directly: 
{ _id:{$gt: ObjectId("57c03e6288579757b5172d51")}}